# Trying to install Maven on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, maven, path-variables

I've downloaded Maven, extracted the zip file, added the bin folder to my PATH variable...but anytime I try to use the command "mvn -v" in PowerShell, all it does is minimise the command window for some strange reason

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried cmd?

Comment: CMD is being weird for me. Anytime I open i, it closes automatically

Comment: Then you have a Windows problem, not a Maven problem.

Comment: Have you tried `java -version`?

Comment: Yeah. that works fine

Answer (score 0):

try finding cmd in programs list and run it as administrator see if that works may be just your profile cmd is corrupt. create new profile on windows and rerun cmd. thats all i can think of now as it seems to be windows issue than that of powershell.